# jest green check marks not showing on terminal

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I am just getting into js/react testing with Jest. Even though it is supposed to be painless testing it has been a bit painful to me:

In the very beginning of my tests, I used to be able to see each test with a green or red check mark. It was very good visually. Now, I am unable to see the little marks next to the tests and I was wondering if someone could guide to see where in the Jest config I could change this feature.

This is my current display when I run my tests: (no check marks or reference to my specific tests)

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jest only outputs the results of every test when in verbose mode, or when there are tests failing. Try running:

`jest --verbose`

Alternately you can set the option in jest.config.js.

Comment: YES! it worked. Thanks @Mitch Lillie. I was editing the testResultProcessor params instead.

Comment: @Monique Glad to hear it. Please accept as the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can append this in to your package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
 "test": "npx jest --verbose"
}
```

Then run `npm test`

Answer (score 1):

If you have created your project using create-react-app ,you can do either one of the following. You can directly add the --verbose to the test script like below

[image]

or you can create a file named **jest.config.json** in the src folder of your project and add the following code

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

If that also didnt work. open you package.json file and add the following line in the jest configuration

[image]